# Comunicate tow or more pc on a lan with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lan

I have done some simple python programing, but I'm no expert, what I need to do is to comunicate a Raspberry Pi with 12 windows PC's, all of the PC's are connected to UPS do to  frequent power shutdowns that I have in my country, the Pi will act as a "server" and it will be monitoring the power source and in the case of a shutdown it will send a command to execute a script on each PC so that they can perform a correct shutdown sequence.

I know how to work with the Pi's GPIO on python, but I have no clue how to communicate then over the LAN.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use TCP socket. Just read [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html), and you will get the idea.

Comment: https://lifehacker.com/5275652/shut-down-your-windows-pc-remotely-from-linux

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is by forking off a process using the subprocess module, and calling the command:

```
net rpc shutdown -f -t 0 -C 'message' -U userName%password -I xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt
```

source: [Shutdown Windows machine from linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936986/shutdown-windows-machine-from-linux-terminal)

As far as I can tell, there are no python modules that offer a nice implementation of the 'net rpc' tools, so calling them using subprocess is the easiest way. To handle the feedback from the command, I suggest you pipe stdout and stderr back to python and then capture and raising exceptions by scraping the output for keywords.

By no means is this the most Pythonic way, I would be interested to see if anyone else has a more Pythonic way of doing it!

Comment: Did this work for you? Can you accept the answer if it did?