# Restart remote windows server through php script remotely

Tags: php, batch-file, server, remote-server, shutdown

I want to restart windows server remotely through the php script. But I am unable to do that.

I have created the .bat file on the windows server but I am unable to reach to that file remotely. I am using exec() function to do that using php

```
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\WINDOWS\abc.bat');
exec('shutdown -r -f -t 10 -m \\\\IP-ADDRESS -c "please wait system is rebooting"');
```

Comment: Is `abc.bat` on the _remote_ machine? The only way to get it to run on the remote machine is to execute a command on that machine. The first `exec()` will try to run a local script on the local machine. The second looks like it should restart the remote machine. What does `abc.bat` do?

Comment: `abc.bat` is used to restart a remote machine. that is on the remote machine.
`exec('shutdown')` command is now working fine from my local machine but it's not working when I upload my code to my server. I am using ubantu server to upload the file

Comment: Are _both_ machines (the "server" where the PHP is run and the "remote" machine you wish to reboot) running Windows?

Comment: no one is running ubantu and the other one is windows

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9937197/2092609) says how to issue a shutdown command from Linux.

Comment: The commands you've listed here will only work when run in Windows. They won't exist on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

for REBOOT

```
exec('shutdown /r');
```

To shut down your computer, type shutdown /s
To restart your computer, type shutdown /r
To log off your computer type shutdown /l
For a complete list of options type shutdown /?
with this commande you can run cmd under php.

```
exec('start cmd /k C:\WINDOWS\abc.bat');
```

OR

```
shell_exec('/s');
```

```
shell_exec('start cmd /k C:\WINDOWS\abc.bat');
```